# Offline installation of El Capitan from a Windows machine?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, install

My macbook pro OS X is broken behind repair and I need to re-install the OS X. Unfortunately it seems the online installation is not working, because it stops downloading about half way through and never completes.

In any case, I only have access to Windows machines. Is there any way to create a USB bootable drive to install El Capitan on my macbook pro 13' (late 2014)?

Any other way to do an offline installation?

Comment: You might also want to check ebay.....just sayin'

Answer (score 1):

If there is an [Apple Store near you](http://www.apple.com/retail/storelist/), you can go in and they will allow you to download the installer.

[image]

You may also be able to find someone who can create the installer for you.